# PHP: Script failing after PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

During my create user process I make a few queries to various database's to get the new user setup. This script has been working fine for about a year and a half, but now something is off.

So the first thing I do is I check to see if a user exists with the credentials being submitted. I've thoroughly tested the check and I'm confident my issue isn't there.

If that check comes back false then the script continues to create the user.

```
public function registerUser() {
 parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $data);
 $data = (object) $data;

 $check = json_decode($this->checkUserExists($data->email));

 if ($check->res) {
  $res = new \stdClass();
  $res->res = false;
  $res->user_status = $check->user_status;
  $res->msg = 'User exists.';
  echo json_encode($res);
 }

 if (!$check->res) {
  $this->createUser($data);
 }
}
```

The problem arises after all the queries have been completed, the script does not seem to want to run the if statement at the bottom. I marked it with comment characters so it's easier to find, but I included the entire function for clarity, maybe I'm doing something that is causing the issue.

I tried invoking an error manually at various points during the script. And I am able to trigger an error all the way down to the bottom of the script.

```
private function createUser($data) {
 $Crypt = new CryptController();
 $AuthSelect = new AuthController();
 $Time = new TimeController();
 $remote_address = new RemoteAddressController();
 $Session = new SessionController();
 $AuthInsert = new AuthModel_Insert();

 $hashed_password = $Crypt->create_hash($data->password);
 $data->password = '';
 $AuthData = json_decode($AuthSelect->getAuth());
 $system_auth_id = $AuthData->system_auth_id;

 $user_id = $Crypt->get_uuid();
 $user_auth_id = $Crypt->get_uuid();
 $user_createddate = $Time->time();
 $user_updateddate = $Time->time();
 $user_lastupdateddate = $Time->time();

 $agent_ip = $remote_address->getIpAddress();

 $userData = $this->createUserObject(
  $user_id,
  $user_auth_id,
  $system_auth_id,
  $hashed_password,
  $user_createddate,
  $user_updateddate,
  $user_lastupdateddate,
  $data
 );

 $agentData = $this->createAgentObject(
  $user_id,
  $agent_ip,
  $data
 );
 //////////////////////////////////////////
 $create_user = $AuthInsert->createNewUser(
  $userData
 );

 $create_user_agent = $this->setUserAgent(
  $agentData
 );

 $sessionKeyData = new \stdClass();
 $sessionKeyData->user_id = $user_id;
 $sessionKeyData->user_auth_id = $user_auth_id;
 $sessionKeyData->system_auth_id = $system_auth_id;
 $sessionKeyData->agent_id = $create_user_agent->agent->agent_id;

 $set_session_key = $Session->setSessionKey(
  $sessionKeyData
 );

 $send_activation_email = $this->createUserActivation(
  $userData
 );

 if (
  $create_user &&
  $create_user_agent->res &&
  $set_session_key->res &&
  $send_activation_email->res) {
  $res = new \stdClass();
  $res->res = true;
  $res->msg = 'New user successfully created.';
  echo json_encode($res);
 } else {
  $res = new \stdClass();
  $res->res = false;
  $res->msg = 'Error: User creation process incomplete.';
  echo json_encode($res);
 }
 //////////////////////////////////////////
 trigger_error("Invoked Error: ",E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

The queries themselves go through just fine, all the tables are populated just fine. The issue is that after that happens the script doesn't finish. It seems to end the `createUser()` function and return to the `registerUser()` function at which point the user will exist so it will return false and echo that back to the client.

In my testing it seems my issue might be at the bottom with that if statement. But I've tested each of those queries individually and they do return the desired booleans to get the `true` condition. But, even the `false` condition doesn't go through which should return `'Error: User creation process incomplete.'`. That doesn't happen either.

I'm hoping someone sees something I'm missing because I've been stuck on this problem for too long. I appreciate any guidance that might lead me to an answer. Thanks in advance.

Just for clarification the message I'm getting back is `$res->msg = 'User exists.';` which comes from `registeruser()`. The message I'm expecting back is `$res->msg = 'New user successfully created.';` which should come from `createUser()`.

Comment: have you looked in the logs for any errors that are being reported? Is error-reporting turned on?

Comment: what do you mean by `it seems that this query is doing something funny`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was a long day yesterday. I do have logging enabled and the logs only showed that I was having an issue with my mailer script which I fixed and this issue still persists. After fixing the mailer issue I don't get any new error logs and the issue still persists. However I'm not so sure it's the queries that are causing the issue anymore it might be my syntax but I can't see anything wrong with it which is why I need another pair of eyes.

Comment: @imposterSyndrome

Comment: if you `var_dump($check)` what is the output

Comment: It outputs `$res->msg = 'User does not exist.'` which is what it is supposed to output when the email wasn't found in the database. I verified that a few times, even intentionally tried breaking that script to make sure it was right. @imposterSyndrome 

It only outputs the message since I'm sure you noticed it's an object, just wanted to clarify. Thanks.